# 2 dice are rolled: what is P(at least one lands on 6 | dice land on different numbers)?

Tags: probability

$P$(at least one 6)$=1-(\frac{5}{6})(\frac{5}{6})=\frac{11}{36}$

$P$(different numbers)$=(\frac{6}{6})(\frac{5}{6})=\frac{30}{36}$

I know that $P$(at least one six | different numbers) = $\frac{P(at least one six) \cap P(different numbers)}{P(different numbers)}$, right? So that would equal $\frac{\frac{11}{36} \times \frac{30}{36}}{\frac{30}{36}}=\frac{11}{36}$? However the book's answer is $\frac{1}{3}$, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P\left[\text{at least one on }6\mid\text{on different numbers}\right]=\frac{P\left[\text{at least one on }6\wedge\text{on different numbers}\right]}{P\left[\text{on different numbers}\right]}=\frac{10}{30}$

There are $1\times 5+5 \times 1=10$ possibities for 'at least one on $6$ **and** on different numbers' :$(6,1),\dots ,(6,5),(1,6),\dots,(5,6)$

Comment: What about $(6,6)$?

Comment: Then the numbers are not different.